# How to put automatically a phone number while calling

Tags: android

I'm trying to Make a little app which when I click on a button it makes a call and after few seconds (in the same default dialer activity) it displays automatically another number in the same default dialer activity.

I tried few ways but it didn't work !

there is my code for now :

```
Intent localIntent5 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            localIntent5.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0153204255"));
            startActivity(localIntent5);

//wait a few seconds

            localIntent5 = getIntent();
            localIntent5.setData(Uri.parse("tel:71 0651755275%23"));
            startActivity(localIntent5);
```

For now it just call the first number

Is it possible ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use auto link for this purpose

```
<TextView 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:autoLink="phone"
 android:text="@string/phoneValue"/>
```

Comment: it doesn't work...
When I click on a button I want my app to call a number and after few seconds in the same default dialer activity it open the default keyboard of the default dialer activity and put automatically a number...